# Compare two .txt files

Tags: powershell

I have issue with compare two text files line by lines. I get the transmission in bytes on each port on the switch. I want to compare the line between the two text files. I need to keep the order of the individual rows and write difference to the column. So I can then evaluate which port does not change.

My code:

```
$ReferenceFile = Get-Content C:\Data1.txt
$CompareFile = Get-Content C:\CompareData1.txt

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $($ReferenceFile) -DifferenceObject $($CompareFile) -IncludeEqual |
    Format-Table -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders |
    Out-File C:\Compare1.txt
```

[image: My text files, Data1, CompareData1, Compare]

Comment: You may want to use CSVs that include the port number with the byte count as input. Otherwise you probably need to implement a line-by-line comparison yourself (with a `for` loop).

Comment: My idea is two for cyclic loops with an index and compare the same index (the same row in both files). Then, you then print out the Port + index to get individual changes on the equivalent lines. It's okay?

Comment: That basically is what my second sentence says, yes. You need only one loop, though, b/c the index is the same for both files.